# When should you use nested subsystems inside usecase diagrams?

Tags: uml, use-case

I was wondering about a use case scenario for a nested subsystem. Right now, I get on why and how to use subsystems, but when should a nested subsystem be used?

In the picture below, I decided to create 2 different subsystems as they have their own business logic, but they are for the same company. Is it necessary to put them in one big sub-system called "Intera" (company name)?

[image: Example Use Case Diagram]

Comment: Looks ok. Usually you just use boundaries to show (sub) systems.

Comment: ethically responsible?

Comment: @Ewan The OP's mother language is likely not English. It's probably "Is it ok to..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The problem with your diagram

Your diagram does nor represent what you think.  It represents [packages](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams.html#package) containing use cases, and no systems nor sub-systems.

Packaging means that the use-cases somehow belong together in the modelling.  But it doesn't say that they are in the same subsystem.

## How should you do it in UML ?

In a use-case diagram, the [***subject***](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-subject.html) is the system / subsystem / component that applies to the use-cases, i.e. the use-cases specifies a unit of useful functionality that the subject provides to its users. According to the UML specifications:

> A subject for a set of UseCases (sometimes called a system boundary) may be shown as a **rectangle** with its name in the top-left corner, with the UseCase ellipses visually located inside this rectangle. The same modeled UseCase may be visually depicted as **separate ellipses within multiple subject rectangles**.

So, strictly speaking, showing the same use-case in a system and in a sub-system requires two elipses.  In practice, you should have separate drawings for each system or subsystem.  Nesting is not formally foreseen.

It's not without reason:  the good practice is to focus use-case diagrams on the behaviors [relevant for the users (external actors)](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-diagrams-questions-answers.html).  The goal is not to reason about the internal structure of the system.  Sub-systems are not relevant for the actors.

The structuring in sub-systems is normally not the first thing that matters when analysing requirements.  In "The Unified Process" for example, the UML inventors explain how to start with requirement-based use-cases, and then make decision on the subsystem architecture at a later stage based on interactions identified between the [entities, controls and boundaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary) that map UC in class-diagrams.

## In practice

Now that's the theory. I can reinsure you that in practice you would not be the first one to draw nested rectangles (but please use rectangles and not packages).  It's not fully legit, but it's an accepted practice.

Comment: `showing the same use-case in a system and in a sub-system requires two elipses` - Doesn't this depend on how you define the system/sub-systems? I can imagine a system where subsystems may be a web app and mobile app where I would expect an ellipse in the subsystems that a user could use to perform the use case. But I can imagine a system where the system is a collection of sub-systems and each use case is realized by interacting with one particular subsystem and the ellipse would only be contained in the subsystem. This kind of goes to the point `Sub-systems are not relevant for the actors`.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I think it's a question of the perspective (and how you split sub-systems). A UC might have the same name in different systems but have (slightly) different added values. Is that good practice? Probably not, but it always depends.